# Remove Double Quote when Generate CSV file use PHP

Tags: php, csv

right now im doing task about generate CSV file use PHP. when i open the CSV file, it display double Quote for currency format number and also it become separate because the currency contain comma. i share the image below

[image]

the correct display should be like this in 1 cell

- $90,178.88
- $90,185.45

here is my code

```
$totalPayout = "$90,178.00";
$totalFees = "$0";
$totalSales = "$90,185.45";
            
fwrite($file, "Generate Report Date , ".date("Y-m-d")."\r\n"); 
fwrite($file, "From (dd/mm/yyyy), ".$datefrom.", ,Total Payout, \"".$totalPayout."\"\r\n"); 
fwrite($file, "To (dd/mm/yyyy), ".$dateto.", ,Total Fees, \"".$totalFees."\"\r\n");  
fwrite($file, " , , , Total Sales, \"".$totalSales. "\"\r\n");
```

because currency have comma so i set the code like this

```
\"".$totalSales. "\"
```

how can i fix this.. i want is, when the CSV file open to excel. it will display a correct format without double quote or separate

please help

Comment: Instead of building the CSV manually, use [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and let PHP handle all that for you.

Comment: The quotes are needed to indicate that the commas in the numbers aren't field separators.

Comment: Post the exact csv file you generate to check its format.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a csv file, you have to say Excel there is an optionnal quote delimiter.

Or put it on all the cells, not only prices

Comment: if i put it on all the cell. it will be like this ?
fwrite($file, "\"From (dd/mm/yyyy), ".$datefrom.", ,Total Payout, ".$totalPayout."\"\r\n");